# combine 2 select mysql base in one

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make something like that. the system must be inside an input and by keywords search on the table specification_group_description.
if I write P, I have the list about all P. there processor
if I write O, I have element of processor and motherboard

Processor (specifcation_group_description)

----- Intel (specification_description)

----- AMD

Motherbooard

-----  XXXX

-----  YYYY

My goal is to create an sql on that, but don't know if my aproach is good.

I think i should merge to db

First

```
SELECT agd.name
FROM clic_specification_group_description agd,
 clic_specification_group sg
WHERE agd.specification_group_id = sg.specification_group_id
AND agd.language_id = 2
```

second

```
select *
FROM clic_specification a,
     clic_specification_description ad
WHERE ad.language_id = 2
and a.specification_id =ad.specification_id
ORDER BY ad.name
limit 10
```

The result must be (don't work)

```
 select *,
(
    SELECT agd.name
    FROM clic_specification_group_description agd,
     clic_specification_group sg
    WHERE agd.specification_group_id = sg.specification_group_id
    AND agd.language_id = 2
)
 FROM clic_specification a,
      clic_specification_description ad
    WHERE ad.language_id = 2
    and a.specification_id =ad.specification_id
    AND ad.name like"%$keywords%"
    ORDER BY ad.name
    limit 10
```

Below the table

```
--
-- Structure de la table `clic_specification`
--

CREATE TABLE `clic_specification` (
  `specification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `specification_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Contenu de la table `clic_specification`
--

INSERT INTO `clic_specification` (`specification_id`, `specification_group_id`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(1, 6, 1),
(2, 6, 1),
(3, 6, 3),
(5, 3, 2),
(11, 3, 8),
(12, 5, 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `clic_specification_description`
--

CREATE TABLE `clic_specification_description` (
  `specification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Contenu de la table `clic_specification_description`
--

INSERT INTO `clic_specification_description` (`specification_id`, `language_id`, `name`) VALUES
(5, 1, 'test 2'),
(3, 1, 'Clockspeed'),
(2, 1, 'No. of Cores'),
(1, 1, 'Description'),
(11, 1, 'test 8'),
(12, 2, 'Description'),
(2, 2, 'Nbr. de Cores'),
(3, 2, 'fréquence'),
(5, 2, 'testfr 2'),
(11, 2, 'testfr 8');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `clic_specification_group`
--

CREATE TABLE `clic_specification_group` (
  `specification_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Contenu de la table `clic_specification_group`
--

INSERT INTO `clic_specification_group` (`specification_group_id`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(3, 2),
(4, 1),
(5, 3),
(6, 4);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `clic_specification_group_description`
--

CREATE TABLE `clic_specification_group_description` (
  `specification_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Contenu de la table `clic_specification_group_description`
--

INSERT INTO `clic_specification_group_description` (`specification_group_id`, `language_id`, `name`) VALUES
(6, 1, 'Processor'),
(5, 1, 'Motherboard'),
(4, 1, 'Technical'),
(3, 1, 'Video'),
(3, 2, 'Vidéo'),
(4, 2, 'Technique'),
(5, 2, 'Carte mère'),
(6, 2, 'Processeur');

--
-- Index pour les tables exportées
--

--
-- Index pour la table `clic_specification`
--
ALTER TABLE `clic_specification`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`specification_id`);

--
-- Index pour la table `clic_specification_description`
--
ALTER TABLE `clic_specification_description`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`specification_id`,`language_id`);

--
-- Index pour la table `clic_specification_group`
--
ALTER TABLE `clic_specification_group`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`specification_group_id`);

--
-- Index pour la table `clic_specification_group_description`
--
ALTER TABLE `clic_specification_group_description`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`specification_group_id`,`language_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT pour les tables exportées
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT pour la table `clic_specification`
--
ALTER TABLE `clic_specification`
  MODIFY `specification_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=14;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT pour la table `clic_specification_group`
--
ALTER TABLE `clic_specification_group`
  MODIFY `specification_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

first result but display all language not only one

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.specification_id AS id,
    sd.name AS name,
    sgd.name AS group_name
FROM  clic_specification s
LEFT JOIN clic_specification_group sg ON ( s.specification_group_id = sg.specification_group_id )

left join clic_specification_group_description sgd on (sg.specification_group_id = sgd.specification_group_id) ,
    clic_specification_description sd
WHERE
    sd.name like '%f%' 
    AND s.specification_id = sd.specification_id 
    AND sg.specification_group_id = sgd.specification_group_id 
    AND sd.language_id = 2
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I dont understand your goal, beacause the fields doesent match, at least in my mind, can you share 'clic_specification_group_description', 'clic_specification_group', 'clic_specification', 'clic_specification_description' structure in some way?

Comment: @UrielChami I insert the database

Comment: ok, fine, and what do you want to do? To search with some cryteria? Which is the cryteria?

Comment: @UrielChami If I write in (Intel), it must take processor and Intel

Comment: Your approach is not right, you need to join tables and stablish only one cryteria, only one where

Comment: I want to write a solution, but Im still not able to figure out the whole thing, I need a computer to apply the inserts and test

Comment: One more question, you are searching for category name? I mean, if I search 'Process' should something appear?

Comment: @UrielChami I created this db, but I have a problem on language, 2 is the french and it write also english. see last element

Answer (score 0):

Found

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.specification_id AS id,
    sd.name AS name,
    sgd.name AS group_name
FROM  clic_specification s
LEFT JOIN clic_specification_group sg ON ( s.specification_group_id = sg.specification_group_id )

left join clic_specification_group_description sgd on (sg.specification_group_id = sgd.specification_group_id) ,
    clic_specification_description sd
WHERE
    sd.name like '%f%' 
    AND s.specification_id = sd.specification_id 
    AND sg.specification_group_id = sgd.specification_group_id 
    AND sd.language_id = 2
    AND sgd.language_id = 2
LIMIT 10
```